# Can’t connect AWS Account using cli

Tags: amazon-web-services, get, command-line-interface

Can not connect to my AWS account using AWS CLI, I was following all procedures explained

1. Creating IAM user with programmatic access
2. Saving secret keys
3. Using `aws configure` command
4. Enter the value that I saved in the csv file
5. Check the credentials and it sounds good for saving the default values
6. Saving token by using the command `aws configure set aws_session_token "" --profile default` and checking the credential file for saving it
7. When I checked the IAM list user it reply with invalid client token id

Did I miss something?

Comment: you need to provide the details on the commands and any error output from which you have concluded that you are unable to connect.

Comment: What is Step 6 doing? You should not define a Token when using permanent credentials. It is only used for Temporary credentials obtained from AWS Secure Token Service (STS).